# How can I check if a string contains another string in C#

Tags: c#

I have strings like this:

```
var a = "abcdef  * dddddd*jjjjjjjjjjjjj";
var b = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa * aaaaaa";
var c = "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh";
```

Is there a smile way for me to check if the string contains a " * " within the first 20 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
a.IndexOf('*') >= 0 && a.IndexOf('*') < 20
```

Should work like a charm

Edit: IndexOf will also return -1 if the char wasn't found at all, which could be useful information i guess.

Comment: You forgot to also check for `> -1`

Answer (score 3):

```
a.Substring(0, 20).Contains('*');
```

Comment: This will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the string has a length less than 20.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool contains = (a.Length > 20) ? a.Substring(0, 20).Contains("*") : a.Contains("*");

if(contains)
{
  etc...
```

Comment: This will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the string has a length less than 20.

Comment: @Jk - I tried all the solutions but there is a problem. What if the line is less than 20 characters long?

Answer (score 2):

This will do it, but you should check the string length -- this code will fail if the string is too short:

```
bool b1 = a.Substring(0, 20).Contains('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

```
 a.Take(20).Contains('*')
```

This is the simplest and efficient than sub string based solution as it doesn't create new string object